# c# sqlite not loading after reopening program

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I have a simple program written in c# and I am using SQLite to save a list of profiles (emails, passwords). Everything works great until I close the program and then reopen it. When I do that the table is empty. This code is located in my form constructor that fires first when the program loads (it's a single form program, very basic). I am using the *System.Data.SQLite* library. I can see the file in my project folder (bin/debug/..). Can anyone please explain why this information is not being saved and available to read on reopening the program?

```
SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("MyDatabase.db");
m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.db;Version=3;");
m_dbConnection.Open();
string sql = "CREATE TABLE " + profileTable + " (" + emailCol + " VARCHAR(320), " + passwordCol + " VARCHAR(30))";
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
sql = "SELECT * FROM "+profileTable+" order by "+emailCol+" desc";
command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    emailProfileListBox.Items.Add(reader[emailCol] as String);
}
```

Here is my INSERT statement that does insert and has been validated.

```
string sql1 = "INSERT INTO "+profileTable+" ("+emailCol+", "+passwordCol+") VALUES (\'"+from_email_address.Text+"\', \'"+passwordTextBox.Text+"\')";
SQLiteCommand command1 = new SQLiteCommand(sql1, m_dbConnection);
command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: `SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("MyDatabase.db");` <= that would be my guess. If you create a new file every time it runs the file would be overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First line, if you create a new file every time it runs the file would be overwritten.

```
SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("MyDatabase.db");
```

Wrap the creation statement in an `if` block instead checking to see if the file exists on disk.

```
if (!System.IO.File.Exists("MyDatabase.db")) 
{
   SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("MyDatabase.db");
   // continue your creation script here
}
```

---

See the [documentation](http://help.crestron.com/simpl_sharp/html/M_Crestron_SimplSharp_SQLite_SQLiteConnection_CreateFile.htm)

> Creates or overwrites a database file in the specified path. This just creates a zero-byte file which SQLite will turn into a database when the file is opened properly. Note that an existing file will be overwritten.

---

#### Side notes

- You should also wrap your connections and any other instances where the type implements `IDisposable` in `using` blocks to ensure that external resources are always released.
- You should use parameterized statements for any values you pass to them. So your inserts, updates, and conditions in your selects should use parameters to pass the values.
- Never store passwords, not even encrypted ones. Create a one way salted hash of the password instead and store that. There are plenty of existing libraries / code fragements out there that can do this for you.

Comment: You can also check for the existence of tables as well. `conn.Execute($"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {TableName} ({TableDefinition})")`

Comment: Thank you, As for the password thing you are also correct but in this instance the security is not important and holds no weight. this is just a very simple program I made for my work and will never see anything outside of my office. Thank you again, your the best!

Comment: Got it. noob here

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because you are creating the table when you rerun the program?